# How to prevent line from being cut off at the bottom when Jasper report is rendered in HTML?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a text field that does not display the text correctly when the report is rendered in HTML. The first example below shows what it should look like.

[image: pdf display]

In the example below, you can see that the letters 'g' and 'p' are very clearly cut off at the bottom.

[image: Arial Unicode MS]

In this next example, the font face is changed to Times New Roman; even though the letters 'g' and 'p' are more distinctly visible, you can see that they are still being cut off at the bottom.

[image: Times New Roman]

This is the source for that text field:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement key="textField-158" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="96" y="33" width="400" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean ($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()==1)]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <box>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dashed" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
        <font fontName="Arial Unicode MS" size="9" isBold="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{4_TOKEN_STATUS_DISPLAY_LIST}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

What should I do to make the text show correctly in the HTML version of the Jasper report?